# intern-geezer never responding on BrowserStackTunnel

Tags: unit-testing, intern, browserstack

I am trying to get intern-geezer *(so far tested on 2.0.1 and 2.1.1)* to work so I can perform tests on IE8 as well.
Currently I am trying to run tests on BrowserStack but unfortunately the test script seems to freeze and never return a response, so I have to stop the process manually.

My configuration is:

#### test/simpleTest.js

```
define(['intern!object', 'intern/chai!assert'], function (registerSuite, assert) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'simpleTest',
        sum: function () { assert.strictEqual(2 + 2, 4, 'Should sum'); }
    });
});
```

#### test/intern-geezer.js

```
define({
    proxyPort: 9000,
    proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
    capabilities: { 'selenium-version': '2.41.0' },
    environments: [
        { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '9',  platform: 'WINDOWS' }
    ],
    tunnel: 'BrowserStackTunnel',
    suites: [ 'test/simpleTest' ],
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:test|node_modules)\//
});
```

Then calling `intern-runner`

```
./node_modules/intern-geezer/bin/intern-runner.js config=test/intern-geezer.js 
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
BrowserStackLocal v3.3
Ready
Initialised internet explorer 9 on WINDOWS
```

Then it keeps there forever doesn't matter what the environment is.

when checking BrowserStack for Exceptions, it seems this is the last operation step to run before it freezes:

```
Get URL⇒ http://localhost:9000/__intern/client.html?config=test%2Fintern-geezer.js&reporters=webdriver&functionalSuites=undefined&suites=test%2FsimpleTest&baseUrl=%2F&sessionId=f07e36f7e73786173ee0cfa98feb7e4b9bff3e2c
```

Any ideas?
*Those tests work fine when using master branch of intern*

Comment: Please try passing a module ID as `config`, not a file path (in other words, remove the `.js`).

Comment: Thanks @CSnover, that worked! If you like to add that as an answer it would be helpful for others falling into the same mistake. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config` command-line argument is supposed to be a module ID, not a filename. In other words, the `.js` needs to be removed.